# calculate dimensions of a circle in c++

Tags: c++, qt4

```
#ifndef CIRCLE_H
#define CIRCLE_H
#include <QString>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class Circle {
public:
  //constructors
  Circle();
  Circle(double r);
  //setter
  void setRadius(double r);
  //getter
  double getRadius();
  //calculate the diameter of a circle
  double computeDiameter()const;
  //calculate the area of a circle
  double computeArea()const;
  //calculate the Circumference of a circle
  double computeCircumference()const;
  //checks if radius of circle is bigger
  **bool isBigger(const Circle& other) const;**

private:
  //private data members
  double m_Radius;
};

#endif // CIRCLE_H



#include "circle.h"
#include "math.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <QString>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

Circle::Circle()
{
  m_Radius =  0;
}

Circle::Circle(double r)
{
  m_Radius = r;
}

void Circle::setRadius(double r){
    m_Radius = r ;
}

double Circle::getRadius(){
    return m_Radius;
}

double Circle::computeDiameter()const{
    return 2* m_Radius;
}

double Circle::computeArea()const {
    return ( m_Radius* m_Radius*M_PI);
}

double Circle::computeCircumference()const {
    return (2* m_Radius*M_PI);
}


#include <iostream>
#include <QTextStream>
#include "circle.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    QTextStream cout(stdout);

    Circle c1,c2;     // input
    c1.setRadius(3);
    c2.setRadius(7);

    cout << "Circle with radius " << c1.getRadius() << " has: " << endl;
    cout<< "Diameter " << c1.computeDiameter() << " cm " <<endl;
    cout<< "Area " << c1.computeArea() << " cm" <<endl;
    cout<< "Circumference " << c1.computeCircumference()<< " cm " <<endl<<endl;

    cout << "Circle with radius " << c2.getRadius() << " has: " << endl;
    cout<< "Diameter " << c2.computeDiameter() << " cm " <<endl;
    cout<< "Area " << c2.computeArea() << " cm" <<endl;
    cout<< "Circumference " << c2.computeCircumference()<< " cm " <<endl<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

**The function isBigger() returns true (or false) if the radius of the Circle instance on which the function is invoked is bigger (or smaller) than the radius of the Circle instance passed to the function.**: I have no idea how to implement this function. Can someone explain this in simple english?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack! What have you tried? And one more thing. Use bold font only to highliting important words.

Comment: I have implemented all the functions except the isBigger one

Answer (score 2):

The implementation would look something like this:

```
bool Circle::isBiggerThan(const Circle& other) const
{
    return m_Radius > other.m_Radius;
}
```

However, it is more idiomatic to use operators:

```
class Circle
{
    // ...
    friend bool operator >(Circle const &, Circle const &) const;
};

bool operator >(Circle const& lhs, Circle const& rhs) const
{
    return lhs.m_Radius > rhs.m_Radius;
}
```

Comment: I think you reversed the operation; the method should be called `isBiggerThan`.

Answer (score 1):

If you know your own radius (`m_Radius` or `getRadius()`) and the other circle's radius (`other.getRadius()`), then you can simply compare them to see which one has the bigger radius, like this:

```
bool Circle::isBigger(const Circle &other) const
{
    return m_Radius > other.getRadius();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make an example, if you have:

```
Circle c1;
Circle c2;
```

Then `c1.isBigger(c2)` should be true if and only if `c1` has a greater radius than `c2`.

(I would probably have called the function `isBiggerThan` to make it easier to say aloud.)

Comment: my question is: which is the radius of the Circle instance on which the function is invoked and which is the the radius of the Circle instance passed to the function?

Comment: u say we should compare c1 and c2?

Comment: @user2548385: I'm telling you how the function is supposed to behave, and I'm leaving it to you to write code that implements that behaviour. (It should take about one line, or less.)

Comment: something like if c1>c2 then c1.isBigger(c2) else c2.isBigger(c1)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
bool Circle::isBigger(const Circle& other) const
{
    return m_Radius > other.getRadius();
}
```

This will simply check the current circle's radius (`m_Radius`) against the given circle's radius.